# Strange FTP behavior when running the "MDelete" Command

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I am running into an issue with the "mdelete" command in FTP when running on Windows 7 Professional 32 bit. Below is what I am getting in the log file after running the mdelete command.

```
ftp> ftp> MDELETE siftinpt.dat
```

Obviously that doesn't execute the command."

I am expecting to see

```
ftp> MDELETE siftinpt.dat
```

A note about the script I am running, we have this same script running on about 100+ PCs that also have windows 7 on them and do not experience this issue. I have never run into this issue before. And we only get this when we run the `MDelete` Command

Comment: What log is that? How do you produce the log? How do you execute the command?

Comment: The log is produced from a batch file that we run to execute the command. The batch file is a child of a parent batch that calls it and set to run from the task scheduler in Windows. "Batch A" calls this batch which downloads the file via FTP and is supposed to delete it but never does because of the above issue.

Comment: So it's a redirected output of the batch? Can you show us the batch?